# Ideals: $I\cdot(J+K)=I\cdot J+ I \cdot K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

For a commutative ring $R$ and ideals $I,J,K$ it is the case that $I\cdot(J+K)=I\cdot J+ I \cdot K$.

I am trying to prove this but I do not understand this step:
We start off by definition $I\cdot(J+K)=\langle i\cdot(j+k)| i \in I ,j \in J, k \in K\rangle$. We have distrubitivity in the ring so $i\cdot(j+k)=ij+ik$. This gives $I\cdot(J+K)=\langle ij+ik| i \in I ,j \in J, k \in K\rangle$. Now we want this to be equal to $\langle ij| i \in I ,j \in \rangle+\langle ik| i \in I , k \in K\rangle$. But how do we justify this?

Comment: Every element of the form $ij$ or $i'k$ lies in the set of elements of the form $ij+ik$ (by taking $k=0$ or $j=0$), giving $IJ+IK\subseteq I(J+K)$. Converseley, every element of the form $ij+ik$ lies in the ideal $IJ+IK$, hence the ideal these elements generate is contained in the ideal $IJ+IK$.

Comment: ah yes! If you would like add your comment as an answer I will accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that every element of the form $ij$ or $i'k$ lies in $I(J+K)$ (by taking $k=0$ or $j=0$). So both $IJ$ and $IK$ are contained in $I(J+K)$, hence so is $IJ+IK$.

Conversely, every element of the form $ij+ik$ lies in $IJ+IK$, so the ideal they generate, namely $I(J+K)$, is contained in $IJ+IK$, giving equality.